# After changing caption text of button Place Order still no change visible

Tags: magento-1.9

I have subzero knowledge of Magento, yet I was asked to change just the Caption of the Button place order as the existing Spanish translation confused customers. So I went to locale and changed the text where it said: Hacer un pedido I wrote Completar este pedido.

I uploaded the csv file back,. but I am still seeing "Hacer un pedido".
I am afraid to mess with the cache or index or whatever because I have no understanding of the inners of magento, but I have not even modified any  php code, just a text of a button. What do I need to do to make the change visible to customers now?

thank you

Comment: clear the cache

Comment: put is as an answer, it has worked fine and has not given me problems. thank you, i will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

After changing locale file just clear the Cache from admin.

`System -> Cache management`